# Terrafrom. Data, archive_file error or bug?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I've a problem with `archive_file` data source.
I've a condition which is creates a lambda layer:

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "layers" {
   for_each = { for layers, name in local.lambdas.options.layers : layers => name if local.lambdas.init.self && local.lambdas.extras.layers }
   filename = "not_working" #data.archive_file.layers[each.key].output_path
   source_code_hash = "not_working" #data.archive_file.layers[each.key].output_base64sha256
   
   ...
}
```

Resource `"aws_lambda_layer_version" "layers"` working as expected, and creates a lambda layer, if `filename` and `source_code_hash` are defined as shown above (Without using data source).

And I have a

```
data "archive_file"  "layers"  {
   for_each = { for layers, name in local.lambdas.options.layers : layers => name if local.lambdas.init.self && local.lambdas.extras.layers }
   type = lookup(each.value.archive, "type", null)
   
   ...
}
```

As you can see, the `for_each` block are same with resource block, but  I'v got an error:

```
each.value is object with 2 attributes
```

Finally here is my module block, where I call this resources

```
layers  = [
   {
      name        = "test-layer"
      runtimes    = [ "nodejs12.x" ]
      archive     = {
         type        = "zip"
      
         ...
      }
   }
]
```

So my question is, why same `for_each` block working differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced your code, for me it is working;

```
resource "null_resource" "cmd" {
   for_each        = { for lambda, name in local.lambdas.init.mods : lambda => name if local.lambdas.init.self && local.lambdas.trigger.laps }
   provisioner "local-exec" {
       command     = lookup(each.value.archive, "command", null)
       working_dir = lookup(each.value.archive, "modules", null)
   }
}
data "archive_file"  "layers"  {
   for_each        = { for lambda, name in local.lambdas.init.mods : lambda => name if local.lambdas.init.self && local.lambdas.trigger.laps }
   depends_on      = [ null_resource.cmd ]
   type            = lookup(each.value.archive,    "type",    null)
   source_dir      = lookup(each.value.archive,    "modules", null)
   output_path     = "${lookup(each.value.archive, "outputs", null)}/${lookup(each.value, "function", null)}.${lookup(each.value.archive, "type", null)}"
   output_file_mode  = lookup(each.value.archive,  "mode",    null)
}
```